# Creating nested structure xml with django

Tags: xml, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I am trying to make xml file from data with `django`.

Here is the list of data which I got:

```
PAGE    PARENT      TAG
1       parenttagA  tag1
1       parenttagA  tag2
1       parenttagB  tag3
1       parenttagB  tag4
2       parenttagC  tag5
2       parenttagC  tag6...
```

...and I want to make a xml file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TAGS>
  <PAGE page="1">
    <PARENT parent="parenttagA">
      <TAG>tag1</TAG>
      <TAG>tag2</TAG>
    </PARENT>
    <PARENT parent="parenttagB">
      <TAG>tag3</TAG>
      <TAG>tag4</TAG>
    </PARENT>
  </PAGE>
  <PAGE page="2">
    <PARENT parent="parenttagC">
      <TAG>tag5</TAG>
      <TAG>tag6</TAG>...
</TAGS>
```

I have attack the problem by `for` tag, but I could not figure out since tags are nested and "PAGE" and "PARENT" tag cannot be written repeatedly. I have also try to solve this issue with combination of `if` and `ifchanged` tags. Although this bring me to close to what I expect, somehow `ifchanged` is always trigger when forloop.counter is 2. Also I thought there could be easier solution which I am not aware of.

Please help me if there is a rational solution for this problem.

---

My messy code:

```
{% for data in datas %}

  {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
  <PAGE page="{{data.pagenum}}">
    <PARENT parent="{{data.parenttag}}">
      <TAG>{{ data.tag }}</TAG>
  {% else %}

    {% if forloop.revcounter == 1 %}
      <TAG>{{ data.tag }}</TAG>
    </PARENT>
  </PAGE>

    {% else %}
      {% ifchanged data.pagenum %}
  </PAGE>
  <PAGE page="{{data.pagenum}}">
    <PARENT parent="{{data.parenttag}}">
      <TAG>{{ data.tag }}</TAG>

      {% else %}
        {% ifchanged data.parenttag %}
    </PARENT>
    <PARENT parent="{{data.parenttag}}">
        {% endifchanged %}
      <TAG>{{ data.tag }}</TAG>

      {% endifchanged %}

    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out!

So `regroup` could be nested and my code should be looks like something like this:

```
{% regroup datas by pagenum as pagenum_list %}
{% for pagenum in pagenum_list %}
<TAGS>
  <PAGE page="{{pagenum.grouper}}">
    {% regroup pagenum.list by parenttag as parenttag_list %}
    {% for parenttag in parenttag_list %}
    <PARENT parent="{{parenttag.grouper}}">
      {% regroup parenttag.list by tag as tag_list %}
      {% for tag in tag_list %}
      <TAG>{{tag.grouper}}</TAG>
      {% endfor %}
    </PARENT>
    {% endfor %}
  </PAGE>
</TAGS>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

either have your data structure better ready for rendering by grouping parents or implement a more advanced solution like [Can I use XSLT in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846827/can-i-use-xslt-in-django)